# Can anyone explain what's happening in below for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, graph

My expected output is

```
4 vertices, 4 edges 

0: 0 1 0 1
1: 1 0 1 0 
2: 0 1 0 1 
3: 1 0 1 0
```

And it works fine without any problem but I don't know what's happening inside the *second **for loop*** in the following **toString()** method statement.

can anyone say what is going on inside this method especially in *for* loop??
And also why this program uses **StringBuilder** instead of **String** data type.

---

```
 public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(V + " vertices, " + E + " edges " + "\n");
            for(int v = 0; v < V; v++) {
                sb.append(v + ": ");
                for(int w : adjMatrix[v]) {
                    sb.append(w + " ");
                }
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
```

---

Here is my full graph program.

```
    public class Graph {

    private int V; // number of vertices in Graph
    private int E; // number of edges in Graph
    private int[][] adjMatrix;

    public Graph(int nodes) {
        this.V = nodes;
        this.E = 0;
        this.adjMatrix = new int[nodes][nodes];
    }

    public void addEdge(int u, int v) {
        adjMatrix[u][v] = 1;
        adjMatrix[v][u] = 1;  // because it is an undirected graph
        E++;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(V + " vertices, " + E + " edges " + "\n");
        for(int v = 0; v < V; v++) {
            sb.append(v + ": ");
            for(int w : adjMatrix[v]) {
                sb.append(w + " ");
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph g = new Graph(4);
        g.addEdge(0, 1);
        g.addEdge(1, 2);
        g.addEdge(2, 3);
        g.addEdge(3, 0);
        System.out.println(g.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You say it works fine, but you're asking how to fix it?

Comment: What part of what loop do you not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every Integer in two-dimensional array adjMatrix, you are appending it's value in StringBuilder (actually just connecting strings).